# How do I print the indices of the three greatest numbers in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Here, `tvalue` is my ArrayList. I have 10 numbers in my ArrayList from `1` to `10`. I want to print the indices of the last three numbers in my ArrayList after sorting it to retrieve the three greatest numbers in the list. However, I am getting inappropriate values as a result. Can anyone help me out? The following is some example code related to my program,

```
        Collections.sort(tvalue);
        System.out.println(tvalue.get(tvalue.size()-1));
        System.out.println(tvalue.get(tvalue.size()-2));
        System.out.println(tvalue.get(tvalue.size()-3));
```

I can't get indices by using this code,
            int index=tvalue.indexOf(tvalue.get(tvalue.size()-1));
            System.out.println(index);

Comment: and what error are yougetting??

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: You already sorted the value, so you're just getting the value back. Make an entirely new `ArrayList` then sort.

Comment: So then do ` int index= initialList.indexOf(tvalue.get(tvalue.size()-1)); `

Comment: i am getting inappropriate index values

Comment: can you please explain it with some code??? -MathBunny

Answer (score 1):

Just to put in code the above explanation:

```
List sortedValue = new ArrayList<>(tvalue);
Collections.sort(sortedValue);
for (int i=1; i<4; i++) {
    System.out.println(tvalue.indexOf(tvalue.get(sortedValue.size() - i)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you sorted the list already, the `indexOf` method does not work. You need to create an initial ArrayList (or List) object, then copy by value everything. Afterwards, sort it like you did above, and then do int index = initialList.indexOf(____).